# jQuery Date Range Picker latestDate is not working?

Tags: jquery, date-range

im using [this](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/) jQuery Date Range Picker and im trying to limit the user for choosing a date in the future in the picker. i tried using latestDate but its not working what is the right way to this ?

```
   jQuery_1_6("#dateRange").daterangepicker({
                earliestDate: Date.parse('1/1/2009'),
                latestDate:Date.parse('today'),
                presetRanges: [
                    {text: 'Last 7 days', dateStart: 'Today-7', dateEnd: 'Today' },
                    {text: 'Last 30 days',dateStart: 'Today-30', dateEnd: 'Today'},
                    {text: 'Last 90 days',dateStart: 'Today-90',  dateEnd: 'Today'}
                ],
                onClose: function() {  }, 
                presets: {
                    dateRange: 'Date Range'
                }
            });
```

Comment: Can we see some code, please?